# In Firebase Analytics, how to filter Events by app version name?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

In Firebase Analytics, I'd like to filter Events by a specific version name of the app.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the **Events** screen, click on **"Add filter +"** button, select the menu **User-scoped custom dimension**, and under the **App version** sub menu, check your target app version.

Comment: Does this refer to VersionCode or VersionName?

Comment: It refers to version name